# Apache Tomcat installation on mac environmentl variable Setup

Tags: java, apache, jsp, tomcat

i have followed some of the guidelines to install apache tomcat 7 and it looks working fine because when i type localhost:8080 after starting it. i can even run any jsp page but none of my servlets are working that i compiled in another place.(different computer). If i write any java program it in text file and compile it will give me so many errors for example it says HttpServlet Class not found or something. i have the tomcat server running computer in my uni so if i try any program over there it works fine but when i try that in my computer it always says Http status 404 and says under description it says the requested resource is not avaliable.
pls help

Comment: One step at a time. First, use an IDE to manage the web application. Second, to compile a program you need all related class files on the classpath.

Comment: How you even do that can you please explain that...

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 2 scopes to think of here. Your compile time scope, and the runtime scope. It sounds as though the httpServlet class is missing from the runtime class path. That is, if it compiles ok, but doesn't find the class at runtime.

You could first check it by putting the jar containing the httpservlet class in the /lib folder in tomcat - if it compiles ok you should be able to see what jar containing the servlet classes is being used at compile time. Then try putting that library in the runtime (i.e. visible to tomcat) class path e.g. /lib.